# Detecting the database a .DAT file belongs to

Tags: database

I have a set of `.DAT` files present along side a set of `.IDX` files with the same name.

The goal is to be able to open these files and read its contents, parsing it into a new format. The problem: I have no idea what database the data is being stored in! The files contain no headers or clues, they are binary, and the resource from which I have received these has no idea as to its storage mechanism.

So the question is: What are some common databases which store databases in `.DAT` files and store their indexes in `.IDX` files with the same name? Is there an application I can use in Linux or Windows which can detect the database?

**EDIT :-**

File names:

- price.dat
- price.idx

Here is a hex dump of the beginning of the `.DAT` file:

> 030D04806420500FFE3E0500002078581001C000738054E0C0099804138100402550080442090082403C101F7406010080C0A010201002010C006FC0246C0403FE00B041C051F0091BFE042F812FE054F8177E066F81BFE078F8207E08AF824FE09CF8297E0AEF82DFE0C0F8327E0D2F836FE0E4F83B7E0F6F83FE5FEFF47C06608480FA91F003C0213101F1BFDFE804220100F500D2A00388430801E04028D4390D128B46804024010A067269FCA546003C0844060E11F084B9E1377850

Here is a hex dump of the beginning of the `.IDX` file:

> 030D04805820100FFD7E0000397FEB60050410007300246A3060068220009BE0401030088B3903F740E010C80402410281402030094004C708004DC058880FFC052F015EBFE042F812FE054F8177E066F81BFE078F8207E08AF824FE09CF8297E0AEF82DFE0C0F8327E0D2F836FE0E4F83B7E0F6F83FFE108F8447E11AF848FE12CF84D7E13EF851FE150F8567E162F85AFE174F85F7E186F863FE198F8687E1AAF86CFE1BCF8717E1CEF875FE1E0F87A7E1F2F87EF5FEFF005E30901714

Both files uniquely start out with `030D04806420500FF` wonder if this is a good start?
Did a quick search on Google but it didn't return anything...

**END EDIT :-**

Any other ideas?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Might be an old c-tree database (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-tree). If its using client based access there wouldn't even be a server to read these files, just some client software with linked access code. Can you post a hex dump of the first 100 bytes or so of one of the file pairs along with the file name?

Comment: added first 120 bytes to description.

Comment: I looked at some old c-tree dat and idx files but they have a different header, sorry. So I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faircom ODBC driver called 'ctreeODBC_RO.exe' which should be capable.